# How to disable Androidstudio “offline” mode？

Tags: android, gradle

My Android Studio version is 2.3. I imported a project from github but it won't build. The error displayed is:
[image: error screenshot]

There's an error displayed, so this must be a common problem. Then  I handle as shown:
  [image: handle screensoft]

But it still doesn't work. It rebuilds in one second and still shows that problem. And the setting switches back to "offline".

The project which I import is this: [github.com/452MJ/C9MJ](https://github.com/452MJ/C9MJ)

So how should I  solve this?
*My native language is not English, so thanks for your patience.